# Getting a list of category child as a dropdownlist for filtering purpose

Tags: kentico

I want to have a filter like a dropdownlist, and the value for the dropdownlist is from `CMS_Category`.

Now I need to know how can I get the specific category of its all child category and initialize it into the dropdownlist?

So I can use it to filter the other repeater while the selected index was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an API to get categories by parent category id:

```
var categories = CategoryInfoProvider.GetCategories().WhereEquals("CategoryParentID", id).OnSite(SiteContext.CurrentSiteID);
```

Binding to dropdown is usual:

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
            ddl.DataValueField = "CategoryID";
            ddl.DataSource = categories;
            ddl.DataBind();
```